# How to make discord bot send scraped message?

Tags: javascript, discord, puppeteer

I want to make an a discord bot that sends a scraped message.
I expected it to send the message but it gave me an error:

> throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

I tried to use message.channel.send(); but it doesn't seem to work.
Code:

```js
let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let Name = document.querySelector('div[id="title"]').innerText;
            let Description = document.querySelector('div[id="content"]').innerText;
            return {
                Name,
                Description
            }
        });
        console.log(data);
        message.channel.send(data);
        debugger;
        await browser.close();
```

Comment: And `console.log("Data",data);` shows data each call?

Comment: @mplungjan I am sorry, but what?

Comment: You have  console.log(data); Can you change it to console.log("Data",data); and if you have a `Data:` line in the console, then the explanation is that the error is correct

Comment: @mplungjan Yes I have a Data: line, What do I do?

Comment: Then I do not know

Comment: @mplungjan Okay, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you shouldn't send the dictionary directly. While `message.channel.send` only accepts [`StringResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/StringResolvable) or [`APIMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/APIMessage), `data` as a dictionary is neither. For more information, see the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send).

Instead, you can convert `data` to a string first. The following is one of the solutions.

```
// Convert using JSON.stringify
message.channel.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Full code example (I tried it on https://example.com and thus there are different queries):

```
let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let Name = document.querySelector('h1').innerText;
    let Description = document.querySelector('p').innerText;
    return {
        Name,
        Description
    }
});
console.log(data);
message.channel.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Message sent by the bot without errors being thrown:

```
{"Name":"Example Domain","Description":"This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission."}
```

If you expect a different message, just make sure that the argument you are passing to `message.channel.send` is acceptable or errors might be thrown.

Comment: Thank you so much!